# Correct binding for ContextMenu in custom control

Tags: wpf, binding, contextmenu

I cannot find the correct binding for a ContextMenu menu item in my custom control.

```
<ContextMenu x:Key="MyContextMenu">
    <MenuItem Header="MyMenuItem"
              Command="{Binding PlacementTarget.MyCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}"/>
</ContextMenu>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyControl}" x:Shared="False">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MyControl}">
                <DockPanel ContextMenu="{StaticResource MyContextMenu}">
                    <!--some controls-->
                </DockPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

MyCommand is defined in MyControl.xaml.cs and is the command I wish to bind to the menu item.

The binding in the example looks for MyCommand in DockPanel.  What is the correct binding?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a tag to the menu's container and bind to it using placement target.

**View this example:**

```
<StackPanel x:Key="ConfigurationListItem" x:Shared="False" Tag="{Binding ElementName=UserControl}">
        <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Tag="{Binding}">
                <MenuItem Header="Sync Environment Dependencies" 
                        Command="{Binding Parent.PlacementTarget.Tag.SyncEnvironmentCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}, Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext}" />
            </ContextMenu>
        </StackPanel.ContextMenu>
    </StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

ContextMenu is not contained in VisualTree. hence no datacontext..
do this to have it working ..

```
<MenuItem Command="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext.MyCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}" />
```

Comment: My control is a Control. The suggestion did not work, even after changing to Control. It yields a binding erorr stating that MyCommand is not a property of ContextMenu. It is my understanding that with a ContextMenu using RelativeSource will only get you back up to the ContextMenu and then you can use PlacementTarget to get its containing control.

Comment: What is a control in wpf ? Never used

Comment: A Control is typically used when you want to create a custom control that allows replacement of its template.  This allows a control's appearance to be completely swapped out for another.

Comment: @DaveK I have changed my answer, this should work, sorry was late last night and didn't see obvious

Answer (score 0):

Mr. Nimrod's answer didn't quite solve my problem, but provided a technique for doing so.  Below is what worked.

The problem with ContextMenu is that you cannot use RelativeSource to traverse the element tree to an arbitrary control: you can only go as far as its container (which you refer to with PlacementTarget).

The basic strategy is to assign Tag in the ContextMenu's container.  Tag refers to whatever control, command, etc. you are interested in.  In my case I assigned it to TemplatedParent, which allowed me to bind to the MenuItem.Command to MyCommand.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyControl}" x:Shared="False">
    <Style.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ContextMenu x:Key="MyContextMenu">
                <MenuItem Header="MyItem"
                          Command="{Binding Parent.PlacementTarget.Tag.MyCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
            </ContextMenu>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Style.Resources>

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MyControl}">                
                <DockPanel ContextMenu="{StaticResource MyContextMenu}" Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                    <!--some controls-->                
                </DockPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```